# Do the Spartan Ops missions in Halo 4 still continue to be released?

Tags: halo-4

I recall that 343 Studios said they will develop 5 new episodes every week. However as the game was released 2012/2013.

Is the program still running?

Answer (score 2):

No. I believe they released 10 episodes in all. They should still be playable, but no additional episodes are planned.